# Is this an edge case in PowerShell's type resolution mechanism?

Tags: powershell, types, type-conversion, powershell-2.0

Here's my situation.  I have a PowerShell module which imports the [PowerShell-JSON](http://powershelljson.codeplex.com/) library; this library converts JSON strings into PowerShell objects.  My module provides an interface to CouchDB, so my JSON strings are obtained from HTTP calls.  I have a function, `Send-CouchDbRequest`, which makes the HTTP request to CouchDB and returns the response data as a string (the response data is obtained using `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()`).

In another function, `Get-CouchDbDocument`, I make a call to Send-CouchDbRequest, and save the output in a variable, `$json`.  According to `$json.GetType()` and `$json | Get-Member`, this is of type `System.String`.  If I then feed this string into `ConvertFrom-JSON`, I expect to get back a `PSCustomObject` with properties defined according to the JSON document supplied to it; instead, I get a string representation of a PowerShell hashtable, i.e., `@{name1=value; name2=value2; name3=value3}`.  The object returned is also of type `System.String` based on the same tests as above, rather than the expected `PSCustomObject`.  It seems to me that PowerShell is doing some kind of automatic (and unwanted/unneeded) type conversion here.

The bug isn't in PowerShell-JSON - I've already [discussed it with the author](http://powershelljson.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=17430), and we have both managed to get the same call to `ConvertFrom-JSON` to work in a dummy module.  I therefore conclude that the error must be in my code somewhere, perhaps a result of the fact that the string has come in over HTTP.

The code for Get-CouchDbDocument is as follows:

```
function Get-CouchDbDocument {
    param(
        [string] $document = $(throw "Document ID is required."),
        [string] $database = $(throw "Database name is required."),
        [string] $server = "127.0.01",
        [int] $port = 5984
    )

    $json = Send-CouchDbRequest -dbHost $server -port $port -database $database -document $document -includeDoc
    $document = $json | ConvertFrom-JSON
    Write-Output $document
}
```

The code for Send-CouchDbRequest is quite lengthy, and [can be found on GitHub](http://github.com/alastairs/posh-couch/blob/master/CouchDB.psm1).  The sample JSON string, that fails in the scenario I have described and works elsewhere, is:

```
{"_id":"f42d2e0c5be0a7ab7bdc1cba23fc1d73","_rev":"1-59414e77c768bc202142ac82c2f129de","key":"value"}
```

Any thoughts?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post result from `Send-CouchDbRequest` to test it? Or is it that one in the issue on CodePlex?

Comment: That's the JSON string from the CodePlex issue.  I'll update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, this one was quite tricky.

What will help you is to change the variable name that stores the object.

```
$doc = $json | ConvertFrom-JSON
Write-Output $doc
```

Reason: you specified in `param` block, that type of the `$document` variable should be `[string]`. That's why PowerShell will try to convert output from `ConvertFrom-JSON` to string.

Other possible solution is to specify the `$document` parameter without the type.

Comment: Face -> Palm.  I'll double-check it when I get home tonight before accepting the answer, but I'm 99% certain this will fix it.  Occam's Razor to the rescue again!

Comment: I didn't see the problem as well, had to try it. Anyway, I hope I found it ;)

Comment: Sorted; thanks so much!  Always helps having another pair of eyes look at it :-)

Comment: Pair programming at home is a little bit difficult ;)